# How to get the select part to send with email

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have made up a form for my cousin that's going to be using it for her class sign ups at her job. What the code does is when you select a option from the first box the second box displays the day, date, and time. I got it working from a recent post I found on here. My problem is that it doesn't show up in a email after someone has submit it.  How can I get it to function so it can get send and show up in a email.

Form example http://crl.x10.mx/rosie_class_form.html

This is what I get in my email...

> Message sent on: Saturday, December 22, 2012
>
> Name:John Doe
>
> Email:yours@email.com
>
> Phone:222-222-2222
>
> Class & Time:  <-- is part not showing up
>
> Comment:
>
> I'll see you there

Everything gets send but the Class & Time part.

html code: (code between the body) choice_1 = Class and choice_2 = Time

```
Name  <input type="text" id="full_name" name="full_name" value="full_name" onBlur="if(this.value == ''){ this.value = 'full_name'; this.style.color = '#BBB';}" onFocus="if(this.value == 'full_name'){ this.value = ''; this.style.color = '#000';}" style="color:#BBB;" /><br /><br />
Phone <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value="xxx-xxx-xxxx" onBlur="if(this.value == ''){ this.value = 'xxx-xxx-xxxx'; this.style.color = '#BBB';}" onFocus="if(this.value == 'xxx-xxx-xxxx'){ this.value = ''; this.style.color = '#000';}" style="color:#BBB;"/><br /><br />
Email &nbsp;<input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="example@domain.com" onBlur="if(this.value == ''){ this.value = 'example@domain.com'; this.style.color = '#BBB';}" onFocus="if(this.value == 'example@domain.com'){ this.value = ''; this.style.color = '#000';}" style="color:#BBB;" /><br /><br />
Select your class and time. 
<br />
<select name="choice_1" id="choice_1" onChange="choice_1(this.'choice_1');">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Class...</option>
  <option value="1">Beginners Cake</option>
  <option value="2">Basic Cake</option>
  <option value="3">Cake</option>
  <option value="4">Candy</option>
  <option value="5">Cookie</option>
  <option value="6">Sugar Cookie</option>
  <option value="7">CupCake</option>
  <option value="8">Flower</option>
  <option value="9">Fondant</option>
  <option value="10">Gum paste</option>
</select>
<br />
<select name="choice_2" id="choice_2" onChange="choice_2(this.'choice_2');">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Time...</option>
  <option value="1">Monday 01/07/13 6:30 to 10:30pm</option>
  <option value="2">Wednesday 01/09/13 5:30 to 7:45pm</option>
  <option value="2">Wednesday 01/09/13 10:00 to 12:00am</option>
  <option value="3">12</option>
  <option value="4">11</option>
  <option value="5">13</option>
  <option value="6">10</option>
  <option value="7">9</option>
  <option value="8">7</option>
  <option value="9">5</option>
  <option value="10">4</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="choice_1" id="choice_1" value=""/>

<input type="hidden" name="choice_2" id="choice_2" value=""/>
<br /><br />
Comments (<span class="optional">Optional</span>) <br />
<textarea name="message" id="message" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
<br /><br />
<strong>Please add these numbers:</strong>

  <span id="digit1"></span> +

  <span id="digit2"></span> =

  <input type="text" id="answer" size="2">
  <br />
 <div id="status"><button type="button" id="myBtn" onClick="ajax_postContact();">Send Now</button></div>
```

class_signups.js (random js name)

```
function s () {

        var choice_1 = document.getElementsByName("choice_1");

        for ( var i = 0; i < choice_1.length; i++ ) {

        if ( choice_1[i].checked ){

        var val = choice_1[i].value;

        return val;

          }

        }

      }
function ajax_postContact(){

    var msg = document.getElementById("message").value;

    var answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;

    var fn = document.getElementById("full_name").value;

    var ph = document.getElementById("phone").value;

    var em = document.getElementById("email").value;

    var digit1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("digit1").innerHTML);

    var digit2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("digit2").innerHTML);

    ///// error checking ////

    var sum = digit1 + digit2;

    if(answer == null || answer == ""){

        alert("Please add the numbers");

        return false;

    }

    else if(answer != sum){

        alert("Your answer to the math problem is wrong. Please try again.");

        return false;

    }

    else if(fn == null || fn == ""){

        alert("Please type your name");

        return false;

    }

    else if(em == null || em == ""){

        alert("Please type your email address");

        return false;

    }

    else if(msg == null || msg == ""){

        alert("Please leave a message");

        return false;

    }

    else{

    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var url = "signups.php";

    var vars = "full_name="+fn+"&phone="+ph+"&email="+em+"&choice_1="+s()+"&message="+msg;

    hr.open("POST", url, true);

    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){

    var return_data = hr.responseText;

    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;

    }

}

    hr.send(vars);

    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "<img src='images/loaderblue.gif' alt='Loader'>";

    document.getElementById("full_name").value = "";

    document.getElementById("phone").value = "";

    document.getElementById("email").value = "";

    document.getElementById("message").value = "";

    document.getElementById("answer").value = "";

    }

}
```

choice1&2.js (goes with the select part)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#choice_1").change(function() { 
if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
    /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
    $(this).data('options',$('#choice_2 option').clone());
    } 
var id = $(this).val();
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
$('#choice_2').html(options);
});
});
```

Comment: Where do you define the functions `choice1()` and `choice2()`? Your `s()` function uses `choice_1[i].checked`, which only makes sense for checkboxes, not select menus.

Comment: @Barmar As for the choice_1[i].checked I have change it to choice_1[i].selected.  What do you mean by define the function choice1() and choice2()

Comment: In your `<select>` you have `onChange="choice_1(this.'choice_1');"`. This tries to call the function `choice_1()`, but you've never defined this function.

Comment: You have both a `<select>` and `<input type="hidden">` with the names `choice_1` and `choice_2`. Why do you need both? The `selected` property doesn't work for the input.

Comment: I had it this way before ' select name="select1" id="select1">' and ' select name="select2" id="select2">' find a post and tried it the onChange and the hidden part.

Comment: You put jquery in your tags. Why don't you use `$('#formid').serialize()` instead of trying to do it yourself?

Comment: Will this function code show up in a email after its submit